# AVAudioSession not working as described by Apple

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

My game has 3 background songs. I would like the game to set the background music to off when there is ipod music playing, else it will play the last played piece of music. When the muser changes the music with the ipod music on, the ipod music should go away and the background music plays. The problem is, the *second time* I try to do this (Changing the music from ipod to in-game) the first song will play but the other two will not.

This is stupid behaviour and it wont work any way I try to solve the problem. Here's my current code....

In the drawRect loop:

```
//Music toggle
                        if(music_active == 0){
                            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:NULL];
                            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:NULL];
                            [background_music play];
                            music_active++;
                        }else if(music_active == 1){
                            [background_music pause];
                            [background_musicB play];
                            music_active++;
                        }else if(music_active == 2){
                            [background_musicB pause];
                            [background_musicC play];
                            music_active++;
                        }else{
                            [background_musicC pause];
                            music_active = 0;
                        }
```

In the startAnimation method:

```
UInt32 size,result;
        size = sizeof(result);
        AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying,&size,&result);
        if(!result){
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:NULL];
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]  setActive:YES error:NULL];
            [background_music prepareToPlay];
            [background_musicB prepareToPlay];
            [background_musicC prepareToPlay];
            if(music_active == 1){
                [background_music play];
            }else if(music_active == 2){
                [background_musicB play];
            }else if(music_active == 3){
                [background_musicC play];
            }
        }else{
            music_active = 0;
        }
```

In the stopAnimation method:

```
[background_music stop];
        [background_musicB stop];
        [background_musicC stop];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:NULL];
        [ [AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:NULL];
```

In the initWithCoder method:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:NULL];
```

This method also loads the sound files and sets the number of loops to -1. It uses AVAudioPlayer, of-course.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the *second time* I try to do this (Changing the music from ipod to in-game) the first song will play but the other two will not"? The second time while running the app? Do you start with iPod music playing, switch the background music (successfully), then play the iPod again without leaving the app, then try to switch the background music again?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comment. Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I meant the second time with a single execution of the application. I load the game and then play the iPod music. I then successfully am able to change the music to the in-game music to whatever I want. When I change to the iPod music again and then try to switch back the second time, the second and third songs fail to play.

Comment: So basically, startAnimation is being called and result will be false because I wont play anything at first. Then stopAnimation is called before startAnimation is called again with result as true. I then switch the music which runs through the code in the drawRect method. It works. stopAnimation is called again before startAnimation is called with result as true for the second time. Switching the music then fails.

Comment: I suppose I may have to deal with this bug for a while and my customers will have to also. It's not a major bug and it's Apple's fault, most likely. I'd like to bring out an update for after my application gets approved in the upcoming days but if I can't fix it, so be it.